# Google App Script + Google Sheet - Loop over each cell in active sheet and add formula with local cell address

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, importrange

I had a search around and couldn't quite find/break apart the information I need to make this work. Apologies if there is indeed a valid question for this already.

**I need to:**

- Fetch the active spreadsheet
- Select every cell in the spreadsheet
- Inject a formula into every cell but crucially it must add the local cell address to the end of the formula I inject. **EG:** *if I inject the formula "=IMPORTRANGE("my.url.com", "My Sheet!!A1") then the next cell should be A2 and the formula should end in A2, repeat from A1 to AA69.*

**For a fuller understanding**

- I am linking two separate Google Sheets together. I use IMPORTRANGE to read in the URL of the target sheet, then I grab the desired 'Sheet Tab' from the target sheet.
- Then I have a template duplicate of the target sheet in which I would like to replicate all the target information. **Eg**: *MySheet is a blank duplicate of TargetSheet, I need to replicate all the info from TargetSheet to MySheet using IMPORTRANGE, however there are many teams that use the same layout sheet but all have unique URLs and I am building a sheet generator, so the script speeds this up massively.*

I have the standard sheet grab that works fine:

```
var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var rangeList = activeSheet.getRange(['A1:AA69']);
```

And i have built my formula from other variables, which comes together easily enough:

```
// Create a combined formula from above variables, at present the only part missing is the cell to inject this into and closing parenthesis.
var IMPORTRANGE_FORMULACONSTRUCT = IMPORTRANGE_BEGINFORMULA_VALUE + "(" + '"' + SPREADSHEETURLVALUE + '"' + ", " + '"' + IMPORTRANGE_INFORMATIONTAB_VALUE + "!" ;
// Print to Logs (View with Ctrl + Enter)
Logger.log(IMPORTRANGE_FORMULACONSTRUCT);
```

How can I loop over every cell and add each cell to the end of my formula?

Help appreciated.

Comment: Using for loop, row and column of your rangeList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the [A1 notation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#geta1notation) of each cell in your range and use it for the local address in your formula.

*Sample:*

```
function myFunction() {
  var IMPORTRANGE_BEGINFORMULA_VALUE = "=IMPORTRANGE";
  var SPREADSHEETURLVALUE = "my.url.com"
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var IMPORTRANGE_INFORMATIONTAB_VALUE = activeSheet.getName();
  var rangeList = activeSheet.getRange('A1:AA69');
  var array=[];
  for( var i = 0; i < rangeList.getLastRow(); i++){
    array[i]=[];
    for( var j = 0; j < rangeList.getLastColumn(); j++){    
      var notation = activeSheet.getRange(i+1,j+1).getA1Notation();
      var notation = rangeList.getCell(i+1,j+1).getA1Notation();
      // Create a combined formula from above variables, at present the only part missing is the cell to inject this into and closing parenthesis.
      var IMPORTRANGE_FORMULACONSTRUCT = IMPORTRANGE_BEGINFORMULA_VALUE + "(" + '"' + SPREADSHEETURLVALUE + '"' + ", " + '"' + IMPORTRANGE_INFORMATIONTAB_VALUE + "!" + notation + '")' ;
      // Print to Logs (View with Ctrl + Enter)
      array[i].push(IMPORTRANGE_FORMULACONSTRUCT);
    }
  }
  rangeList.setValues(array);
}
```

Keep in mind that this code might be slow if you iterate over a large range.

Comment: Thank you for this, it's a big help. I think I understand how you are incrementing each cell. But it seems the script won't run, it breaks on "Cannot find function getRangeList in object Range" which is just before adding the array. I am unsure as to why this happens.

Comment: EDIT: Got it, adding gteSheetByName broke setting the rangeList for some reason.

Comment: The code as provided above works for me. If you want to modify it be careful  - it should be `getSheetByName ` and not `gteSheetByName `.

Comment: Ok: it currently fails at: TypeError: Cannot find function getLastRow in object RangeList.

So I will investigate but if you have any ideas i am curious..

Comment: Did you implement any modifications to the code provided in the sample?

Comment: I have substituted your: var SPREADSHEETURLVALUE = "my.url.com"

For my: var SPREADSHEETURLVALUE = SPREADSHEETURLREFERENCE.getValues();

Which pulls the url link from a specific cell: var SPREADSHEETURLREFERENCE = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MYSHEETTOFETCHURLFROM").getRange("O3");

The rest is the same.

Comment: Got it! There was a mistype on rangeList, must've hit something and made a typo, this all works perfectly! I have amended your script to use my variables and have verified it all, thank you so much!

Comment: If you are pulling a value from a single cell you should use `getValue()` instead of `getValues()`. Otherwise your value will be nested in double square brackets since it will be a 2-D array.